# How to convert long integers in the expression into the products of their prime factors via Mathematica?

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation

I have many of the following expressions which I want to convert using `CForm`:

```
 24612842763116842319872/(5042560366642267*x - 256*(2446745837411900 + 4901398098088043*y - 144207654645973248*z));
```

Another example for testing:

```
-((524288 (29427736469514379027531261659072347+58899562724319710108573382000184640 y-1732944474195510410991057714955859184 z))/(5042560366642267 x-256 (2446745837411900+4901398098088043 y-144207654645973248 z))^2)
```

What is the regular expression rule to use in *Mathematica* in order to convert all the long integers in the output of `CForm` into the product of their prime factors:

```
RegularExpression["regex"]
```

My thoughts are, first extract every long integer, and `FactorInteger` them to obtain all prime factors; then replace the original long integers with product of their prime factors.

The target final expression should be usable immediately in C/C++.

But I have no idea how to use the regular expression rule.

Comment: Hint: don't use regular expressions.

Comment: Your second example is not proper MMA syntax. Pleas post the expresion before applying `CForm`.

Comment: hi @Kuba , it is a "fraction" form as: -((524288 (29427736469514379027531261659072347+58899562724319710108573382000184640 y-1732944474195510410991057714955859184 z))/(5042560366642267 x-256 (2446745837411900+4901398098088043 y-144207654645973248 z))^2)

Comment: So after converting into CForm, it is : (-524288*(29427736469514379027531261659072347 + 58899562724319710108573382000184640*y - 1732944474195510410991057714955859184*z))/
   Power(5042560366642267*x - 256*(2446745837411900 + 4901398098088043*y - 144207654645973248*z),2)

Comment: FWIW, some of your numbers are too big to fit into 64 bits (e.g. Log[2., 24612842763116842319872] is 74.3818)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I also noticed this problem. hi @Kuba, if all the PrimeQ[#] factors will be split into ((#-1)+1), and then further such factorization until all PrimeQ[#] are smaller than 2147483647/2, what the Function would be? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
expr = -((524288 (29427736469514379027531261659072347 + 
    58899562724319710108573382000184640 y - 
    1732944474195510410991057714955859184 z))/(5042560366642267 x - 256 
    (2446745837411900 + 4901398098088043 y - 144207654645973248 z))^2)
```

with `Powers`, general approach

```
ClearAll@f;
f[expr_] := Replace[
    CForm[expr],
    i_Integer /; And[! PrimeQ[i], Abs[i] > 1000] :> (
           Sign[i] (Times @@ (If[#2 == 1, HoldForm @ #, HoldForm[Power[##]]
                                ] & @@@ FactorInteger[Abs@i])))
    , \[Infinity]]

f[expr]
```

> ```
> -(((-(z*(Power(2,4)*3*13*31*3616032431023*24774565539206567657)) + y*(Power(2,6)*5*23*8002657978847786699534426902199) + 
>      1949*15098889927919127258866732508503)*Power(2,19))/
>  Power(x*(7*137*389*50651*266867) - 256*(4901398098088043*y - z*(Power(2,8)*Power(3,2)*11*5690011625867) + 
>       Power(2,2)*Power(5,2)*24467458374119),2))
> ```

Comment: thank you! It is very impressive. How to you handle expression like this: (-524288*(29427736469514379027531261659072347 + 58899562724319710108573382000184640*y - 
       1732944474195510410991057714955859184*z))/
   Power(5042560366642267*x - 256*(2446745837411900 + 4901398098088043*y - 144207654645973248*z),2)

Comment: @LCFactorization take a look at the more general approach, but do not put `CFrom` expresions into `f`, only regular ones.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an idea (without RegExps):

We set up a function `fact` that extracts the prime factors and wrap them in some head, here we use `factors`:

```
fact = factors @@ Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[#]] &;
```

(I use `ConstantArray` to show all factors)

Then we apply this to the expression and replace all integers of absolute value larger than some number:

```
expr = 24612842763116842319872/(5042560366642267*x - 256*(2446745837411900 + 4901398098088043*y - 144207654645973248*z));
n = 10^6;
expr /. x_Integer /; Abs[x] > n :> fact@x
```

and find:

> factors[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
>      2, 41, 683, 15277, 
>     13717003]/(x factors[7, 137, 389, 50651, 266867] - 
>      256 (y factors[4901398098088043] + 
>         factors[2, 2, 5, 5, 24467458374119] + 
>         z factors[-1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 11, 5690011625867]))

Comment: Thank you! How to obtain desired final expression (if there are many ) from the current step?

Comment: @LCFactorization: please define what you'd like to obtain in the final step (this is not fully clear to me). Thanks

Comment: I now think combine both yours and @Kuba's can get the desired results. The desired final expression should be able to be used immediately as C/C++ expression. For example, the factors[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 41, 683, 15277, 13717003] better be Power(2,22)*41*683*15277*13717003, and so on. Thank you; very good idea without using regular expr

Comment: ah ok, I wasn't aware of that syntax, my bad. You could modify `fact` accordingly. Let me know if you need any help & thanks for the feedback

Comment: Thank you for kind reply! I am new; all these are useful for me to learn MMA.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate approach where I teach [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm) how to format integers in the way you desire:

```
Unprotect[Integer];

Format[i_Integer?CompositeQ, CForm] /; Abs[i]>1000 := Replace[
    Apply[HoldForm @* Times] @ FactorInteger[i],
    {
    {n_, 1} :> n,
    {n_, m_} :> Power[n, m]
    },
    {2}
]

Protect[Integer];
```

Here's your examples:

```
CForm[
    24612842763116842319872/(5042560366642267*x - 256*(2446745837411900 + 4901398098088043*y - 144207654645973248*z))
]
```

> (Power(2,22)*41*683*15277*13717003)/
>      (7*137*389*50651*266867*x - 256*(Power(2,2)*Power(5,2)*24467458374119 + 4901398098088043*y - 
>           Power(2,8)*Power(3,2)*11*5690011625867*z))

```
CForm[
    -((524288 (29427736469514379027531261659072347+58899562724319710108573382000184640 y-1732944474195510410991057714955859184 z))/(5042560366642267 x-256 (2446745837411900+4901398098088043 y-144207654645973248 z))^2)
]
```

> (-Power(2,19)*(1949*15098889927919127258866732508503 + Power(2,6)*5*23*8002657978847786699534426902199*y - 
>          Power(2,4)*3*13*31*3616032431023*24774565539206567657*z))/
>      Power(7*137*389*50651*266867*x - 256*(Power(2,2)*Power(5,2)*24467458374119 + 4901398098088043*y - 
>           Power(2,8)*Power(3,2)*11*5690011625867*z),2)